# Angular 5 does not generate some CSS rules from SCSS

Tags: css, sass, angular5

I write an Angular 5 application, and I cannot get some CSS rules generated.
Here is a small example, HTML:

```
<table class="table-rule">
    <tr>
        <td class="cell-rule">demo text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

SCSS:

```
.table-rule {
    font-weight: bold;
    .cell-rule {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

And here is the problem: I should get a bold red text in a table, but I get only red text (not bold). I found out that Angular generates such a CSS:

```
.table-rule .cell-rule { color: red }
```

It does not generate CSS rule for "*.table-rule*" selector. Only for "*.table-rule .cell-rule*" selector.

Any ideas why is it so and how can it be fixed?

P.S. pure HTML+CSS works fine: http://jsbin.com/maxagin/edit?html,css,output

Comment: May be styles on td are overrinding your bold styles on table. Try adding the bold to td instead of the table.

Comment: No, it is not about styles. It is about Angular being wrong here. table-td tags are used here only for demonstrational purposes.

Comment: The code shown would work, so it must be another problem with your configuration or code.

Comment: No, it does not work. Maybe someone else knows what are conditions which cause such a behavior?

Comment: Will down-voters care to explain? Question is related to misbehavior of SCSS compiler and will help anyone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem: in a production .scss file there was an empty comments line between two rules:

```
.rule1 {
    ...
}
/**/ <---- this one!
.rule1 {
    ...
}
```

Removing this comment (/**/) fixed SCSS to CSS conversion.
Strange bug in SCSS.